# Pandas replace nonzero with values 1 for some columns

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe `df` I have some columns (namely 2:11) that take on the value NaN or some text as seen below.

```
  >>> df.head(2)
              Yoga  Cardio_time     Legsfront Legsback    Ass Calf Back Biceps  \
  date                                                                           
  2016-01-15   0.0          3.0  Framsida lår      NaN  Rumpa  Vad  NaN    NaN   
  2001-01-01   0.0         40.0  Framsida lår      NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN   

              Chest Shoulders Triceps    Other  Muscles_time  Stretch_time Notes  
  date                                                                            
  2016-01-15    NaN       NaN     NaN  testing           NaN           NaN   NaN  
  2001-01-01  Bröst       NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN           NaN   NaN
```

For the variables [Legsfront, ..., Triceps] I want to recode so that the NaN values are replaced by zero -- this can be done using `.fillna(0, inplace=True)`. I have done so in the code below. Then I want to recode nonzero to ones, but I cannot do it. I have tried with `dfb[dfb != 0] = 1` and `dfb.Ass[dfb.Ass != 0] = 1`. Maybe a for loop is needed?

```
  >>> binaryvars = ['Legsfront', 'Legsback', 'Ass', 'Calf', 'Back', 'Biceps', 'Chest', 'Shoulders', 'Triceps']
  >>> dfb = df[binaryvars]
  >>> dfb.fillna(0, inplace=True)
  >>> dfb.head(2)
                 Legsfront Legsback Ass Calf Back Biceps  Chest Shoulders  \
  date                                                                      
  2016-01-15  Framsida lår        0   Rumpa  Vad    0      0      0         0   
  2001-01-01  Framsida lår        0   0    0    0      0  Bröst         0   

             Triceps  
  date                
  2016-01-15       0  
  2001-01-01       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas.notnull) [`astype int`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) instead of using `fillna` use:

```
ndf = df.notnull().astype(int)
```

Sample Output :

```
             Yoga  Cardio_time  Legsfront  Legsback  Ass  Calf  Back  Biceps
date                                                                       
2016-01-15     1            1          1         0    1     1     0       0
2001-01-01     1            1          1         0    0     0     0       0
```

In your case you can do

```
binaryvars = ['Legsfront', 'Legsback', 'Ass', 'Calf', 'Back', 'Biceps', 'Chest', 'Shoulders', 'Triceps']
dfb = df[binaryvars].notnull().astype(int)
```

To change data in main dataframe you can use

```
df[binaryvars] = df[binaryvars].notnull().astype(int)
```

Comment: Using `.notnull` is perfect. Ideally I would only be working with `df` and skip `dfb` as the latter was merely a workaround. Can you comment (or modify your answer) so that I can make this directly changing the `binaryvars` in `df`?

Comment: It's simple instead of dfb use 'df[binaryvars] ='